# How to get file resources of a JavaFX WebEngine

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

I am pretty new with JavaFX and I'm using this code (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm) to implement a simple web view with JavaFX. But I'm not able to get all the files (html, css, images, javascript files, cookies, and so on) that make up the web page.

How can I access those files, so that I can work with them?

Answer (score -1):

You can load a `html` using the following methods. The `JS`, `CSS` and other files linked in the HTML will be loaded along with it.

```
webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/location/to-your-file.html").toExternalForm());
```

If you have the file in your local drive, you can use:

```
String URL = new URL("file:///" + ""/location/to-your-file.html").toExternalForm();
webEngine.load(URL);
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I can successfully load a remote web page using the code above: the web view loads all the remote web page, with all its resources, automatically, but I cannot directly access those files. I mean: where does the JavaFX web engine save (all) the resource  files after they've been **automatically** downloaded by the engine? Is there a location on the disk? Or how to get them? I need to access any single file because I have to do some jobs with them, for example I need to get their hashes...